# Non-Printable Characters xsd

Tags: java, regex, xsd

I want to write a regex for an xsd schema.

The string can support 1-20 characters of the following kind:

- Letters (lower case, capital case)
- Numbers
- [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29) Leters ( But multiplication sign \u00D7 and division sign \u00F7)

My schema looks like that:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="^[a-zA-Z0-9\uC0-\uFF-[\u00D7\u00F7]]{1,20}$"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

The pattern works perfectly in .Net (C#) and Visual studio.
Now, If i put it in eclipse, I get the following error:

```
... Is not avalid regular expresion
```

If I try to validate an XML with java SAX Parser, I get the following exception:

```
InvalidRegex:....Is not avalid regular expresion
```

Comment: try `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\uC0-\\uFF-[\\u00D7\\u00F7]]{1,20}$"`

Comment: With your proposal it becomes a valid pattern, but no string is valid in the xml I try( "12345" )

Comment: try `"^[a-zA-Z0-9\\u00D7\\u00F7\\uC0-\\uFF]{1,20}$`

Comment: how about `^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u00FF]){1,20}$`

Comment: Avinash Raj: The same answer as before: xml is not anymore valid

Comment: herrlock: eclipse says "...Is not avalid regular expresion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it now:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[&#x00C0;-&#x00D6;&#x00D8;-&#x00F6;&#x00F8;-&#x00FF;]){1,20}$
```

detail:

a lowercase or uppercase letter or a number

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

or
a latin-1 letter except \u00D7 and \u00F7

```
[&#x00C0;-&#x00D6;&#x00D8;-&#x00F6;&#x00F8;-&#x00FF;]
```

and the whole thing up to 20 times

---

or with the xml-exclude-syntax:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]|[&#x00C0;-&#x00FF;-[&#x00D7;&#x00F7;]]){1,20}$
```

Comment: I see, the problem was the notation. Eclipse didn't recognize the \x but &#x ;, Thanks